Binary Solid-State RF Power Amplifiers
I am looking for information on Binary Solid-State RF Power Amplifiers. I am curious how a commercial AM radio transmitter manufacturer claims 87% efficiency on 10 to 50 kW. I don't understand how a linear amp can run at such high efficiency. Typically, efficiency runs at 60%. Thus, an increase to 87% is a significant leap. I understand traditional linear RF power amplifiers utilizing solid-state or vacuum tube technology.
Here is a link to the Harris 3DX-50 commercial AM transmitter specification brochure. Here is the quote for the RF Power decks: " The 50 kW DX Destiny uses 62 main and six binary solid-state RF power amplifiers." So, what the heck is Binary SS Power Amps, and where can I find more information about them? All I can tell is they use MOSFETs.
Thank You

What is a Class S+ amplifier

A Class-D amplifier can have far greater efficiency than other types, which are analog amplification devices.
With Class-B, for example, amplification of a sinusoidal signal causes the amp to dissipate power because part of the time the output device is not completely on or off. They behave like a variable resistor... in fact, one could make a sine wave by putting a motor on a potentiometer in series with a resistor.
Class-D amplifiers are binary switches... very fast switches. Since, theoretically, they are either off, with no current across the device; or on, with no voltage across it, then power dissipated would be zero I * V, or I * zero V.
Wait! How can a switch create a sine wave? By creating an approximation of the waveform in many small steps, and smoothing the output (digital waveform synthesis). Modern car radios, for example, usually use Class-D output, and the speaker cone, among other parts, cannot respond to the ultrasonic-frequency steps, in effect, averaging them into faithful reproduction of the input waveform.
However, the operative word, above, is theoretically. Semiconductor and other switching devices have frequently limitations, and do dissipate power while transitioning between states, from off to on and back. The higher the frequency, the more difficult to obtain efficient amplification. At audio frequencies, upt to 20 kHz, a Class-D amp might exceed 95% efficiency. At MW (AM broadcast) frequencies, efficiency might drop to the claimed 87%.
At much higher frequencies, Class-D is impractical. The magnetron in a 2.4 GHz home microwave oven is perhaps 65% efficient -- not bad for vacuum tube technology, even though it wastes energy heating the filament. No present electronic device could switch at 24 GHz, to produce ten little steps in one sinusoid, to make a 2.4 GHz Class-D amp.
